# How return count result instead closure function?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function that returns boolean if tree has at least one enebled value:

```
  treeHasEnabledNode(): Function {
    let enabled = false;

    return function isNodeEnabled(node: T): boolean {
      if (!node || !node.children || !node.children.length) return enabled;
      if (node.enabled && node.enabled !== undefined) return true;

      node.children.forEach((node: T) => {
        enabled = isNodeEnabled(node);
      });

      return enabled;
    };
  }
```

Using is:

```
let hasEnabled = treeHasEnabledNode()(this.tree);
```

How to return result not calling outher functon (this.tree)?

Comment: `I have a function that returns boolean if tree has at least one enebled value` - no you don't. That's not what your function does. It only returns true if the **last** value in the array is enabled.

Comment: Why, it returns function that returns boolean if loop faced with first node where enabled = true.

Comment: It overwrites `enabled` each item in the loop. Therefore the value of `enabled` only contains the result of the last item in the loop. What you should have written is `if (!enabled) {enabled = isNodeEnabled(node)}`

Comment: Or `enabled = enabled ? enabled : isNodeEnabled(node);` but I prefer an if statement

Comment: I am not agree, because I have `if (node.enabled && node.enabled !== undefined) return true;` And if node enabled it stops and returns

Comment: I'm not talking about that. I'm talking about the case where both `if` does not return. Then you enter the `node.children.forEach()` loop. It will loop through each children until the end. So if the first children is false `enabled` is false, next if the second children is true `enabled` is true, next if the last children is false `enabled` becomes false again

Comment: I think you think that `Array.prototype.forEach()` will stop processing the array if the callback function uses the `return` keyword. This is not true. It will keep processing the array until the end or until something throws an error

Comment: I'm just trying to help you fix an obvious bug in your code. If you want to keep the bug then it's your choice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go about this a few ways. The most simple one would probably be to invoke the internal function within the outer function, and return the result:

```js
function treeHasEnabledNode(node) {
  let enabled = false;

  function isNodeEnabled(node) {
    // do whatever. for example:
    return enabled
  }
    
  return isNodeEnabled(node);
}

const node = {};
console.log(treeHasEnabledNode(node));
```

However, as @sledetman mentioned in the comments below your question, the code snippet you provided does not "return a boolean if tree has at least one enabled value".